# Java CSS spriting library

Tags: java, css, sprite

I'm looking for a pure Java CSS spriting library that I can integrate into my Maven build, so that spriting would be done automatically for every new build. (I'm currently using http://code.google.com/p/wro4j/ for JavaScript and CSS minimizing)

I was looking into http://csssprites.org/ first but the CSS annotation effort required somewhat put me off. Is there any other library out there I should be looking at?

Comment: Nobody? There should be something. What do Java people use for spriting when they are not using GWT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although not 100% ideal, I went for [SmartSprites](http://csssprites.org/)  in the end. There's a nice [Jangaroo Maven Plugin](http://blog.jangaroo.net/2012/07/managing-sprites-with-smartsprites-and.html), meaning you can integrate the Sprite generation into your Maven build process easily.

Downside of this solution is, that you have to add quite a bit of extra hints into your CSS files, so SmartSprites can do its spriting. Would have been nice, if SmartSprites would (semantically) parse the CSS files and do the spriting automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is exactly what you're looking for. This can create sprite sheets and export the data in many different formats. I posted to it because it has a command line version of it that may be of use. 
http://www.texturepacker.com
http://www.texturepacker.com/store/

Comment: Thanks. Looks promising. I'll definitely check it out.